# Delaying shutdown.exe with parameters

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Using the task scheduler I run shutdown.exe with the paramaters -s -t 350 after it gets dark. What I wish to make is a batch file or similar that extends this duration with a fixed amount of time. So far I've tried the following

```
@echo off
cd %windir%\system32
start shutdown.exe /a
start shutdown.exe /s /t 250
exit
```

Only the /a line works as intended and shutdown.exe is not started again. How come this is the case, and how can it be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `start`, it not the normal way of starting programs.

Comment: I'm new to writing batch files and this worked, if you have a suggestion feel free to add it

Comment: I don't get what you want to do? Please clarify.

Comment: I want the end result to be that my computer will shut down at a certain time on its own, but that I can extend the time it has before shutting down somehow. My idea was to cancel the previous shutdown.exe command and then start a new one, which is what I expected the attached code to do. Hope this clarifies

Comment: No it doesn't. You are using `Start`.

Comment: run `start /?` to know what the command is used for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep telling you to lose `start`. You do not use `start` to start programs normally. Also don't name the batchfile `shutdown`.

```
shutdown.exe /a
shutdown.exe /s /t 250
```